# Capture desktop with FFMPEG on MacOSX 10.6.8

Tags: ffmpeg, osx-snow-leopard, screen-recorder

I tried to capture the desktop/screen-recording with this command

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "1:0" out.mp4
```

this doesn't work because avfoundation is a framework on OSX >= 10.7 and my OS version is 10.6.8 (snow leopard)

I looked at [this](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html) FFMPEG devices reference. Now my plan is to install the right device in mac and than recompile FFMPEG to enable the device. I don't know which device i have to install. Is QTkit the right one?

Comment: tbh, I'd first question **why** still on 10.6.8… the rest would likely be fixed by updating the OS

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried to update to Yosemite but fails all the time in the middle of the  download (the message say that's because a connection problem). I tried also to create a new user and start a new download but the problem still there. I don't know why...

Comment: Then you'd have to try a different connection or get a friend to download it for you.